# C++: std::copy fails with access violation reading location error

Tags: c++, list, copy

I'm trying to copy a list of objects from class that was created by me using the **std::copy** C++ function, but the function crashes with the next error message:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA91BAC570 (msvcr120.dll) in
>   MyProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The class is pretty simple and I have no idea what can cause the copy function to crash with such error.
The class looks as follow:

```
class XMLObjects
    {
    private:
        int id;
        string name;
        int leftUpCornerX;
        int leftUpCornerY;
        int rightDownCornerX;
        int rightDownCornerY;
        bool isFound; //it's true if this object was found in the OR file and in the GT file

public:
    XMLObjects(){}
    XMLObjects(int _id){ id = _id; }
    XMLObjects(int _id, string _name, int _leftUpCornerX, int _leftUpCornerY, int _rightDownCornerX, int _rightDownCornerY) { id = _id; name = _name; leftUpCornerX = _leftUpCornerX; leftUpCornerY = _leftUpCornerY; rightDownCornerX = _rightDownCornerX; rightDownCornerY = _rightDownCornerY; isFound = false; }
    ~XMLObjects(){}

    void setID(int _id){ id = _id; }
    void setName( string _name){ name=_name; }
    void setLeftUpCorner(int _leftUpCornerX, int _leftUpCornerY){ leftUpCornerX = _leftUpCornerX; leftUpCornerY = _leftUpCornerY; }
    void setRightDownCorner(int _rightDownCornerX, int _rightDownCornerY){ rightDownCornerX = _rightDownCornerX; rightDownCornerY = _rightDownCornerY; }
    void objectWasFound(){ isFound = true; }

    int getID(){ return id; }
    string getName(){ return name; }
    int getLeftUpCornerX(){ return leftUpCornerX; }
    int getLeftUpCornerY(){ return leftUpCornerY; }
    int getRightDownCornerX(){ return rightDownCornerX; }
    int getRightDownCornerY(){ return rightDownCornerY; }
    bool isObjectFound(){ return isFound; }
};
```

The call to the copy function looks as follow:

```
list<XMLObjects> objects;
objects.push_front(obj1);
objects.push_front(obj2);
objects.push_front(obj3);
list<XMLObjects> NewObjectsList;
std::copy(objects.begin(), objects.end(), NewObjectsList.begin());
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You have to use `inserter`

Comment: To expand on that, `NewObjectsList` is empty, and `std::copy` doesn't resize it.

Comment: Why not just `list<XMLObjects> NewObjectsList = objects`?

Comment: I would also suggest the following points: (1) The `XMLObjects` constructors should initialize at least all `int`s and `bool`s. And (2) the third `XMLObjects` constructor should move the given `_name` into the member `name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::copy` doesn't resize output, so you have to resize your container before or use special iterator which insert element.

You may use following code.

```
std::copy(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
          std::inserter(NewObjectsList, NewObjectsList.end()));
```

As noted in comment, in your case, you may directly do a copy:

```
list<XMLObjects> NewObjectsList = objects;
```

Comment: Or simply `std::back_inserter(NewObjectsList)`